# similar excel match function in SQL

Tags: sql-server, match

is there any similar  excel match function in SQL.
for example,

```
eng_code 
21, 
23, 
WE,
21,
UR,
...
```

need to find out the first position of 21 in the table. 
sure the same for other eng_code

Comment: Is the data stored as comma separated values in single row or in different rows ?

Comment: is this the content of a column named eng_code with 5 rows in the table, or is this the content of this field in one row ? Please provide more clear sample data

Comment: eng_code is a column, for example , I have 7000 rows as returned data set.  one value for each row. cheers
Y4
UW
Y4
22
RY
UW
UW
TZ
MG

Comment: still very unclear. Please edit your question and add a few rows from that table

Comment: the format makes it look like only one row. in fact, Y4  for one row, Uw as next one, then Y4, 22.  anyway just used row_number for sub query, then use min to get the correct value. so it is sorted. thanks